# Wake On LAN only works when shutting down as root

Tags: wakeonlan

When running `systemctl poweroff` WOL does not work.
Same for `systemctl suspend`, `systemctl hibernate`, etc.
Running `sudo systemctl poweroff` etc. results in WOL working properly.

Also after stopping the machine without sudo `Wake-on` is set to `d` instead of `g`.

So the problem is that `Wake-on` is only set to `g` when stopping the machine as root.
Why is that?

WOL is btw configured through NetworkManager.

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you're running? Without knowing this, proposed answers may be incorrect ...

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 21.10,